# Numpy: Masked elements in computation

Tags: python, numpy, computation

I have a function to built a polynomial from a given x: [1, x^2,x^3,x^4,...,x^degree]

```
def build_poly(x, degree):
    """polynomial basis functions for input data x, for j=0 up to j=degree."""
    D = len(x)
    polyome = np.ones((D, 1))
    for i in range(1, degree+1):
        polyome = np.c_[polyome, x**i]

    return polyome
```

Now, I would like to calculate polynom for a given x, but omiting sume values.

Hence, what this is what I did:

Created X:

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])])
```

[image]

I masked away the value with I wanted to omit:

```
masked_x= np.ma.masked_equal(x, 5)
print(masked_x)
```

[image]

But when I do the computation:

```
print(build_poly(masked_x,2))
```

[image]

The masking has disappeeared. **Why ?** 
I want to have the program omit the masked elements

Comment: Immediately after the `for` statement, add `print(i,x**i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when working with masked arrays one must consistently use the `numpy.ma` versions of the routines. Any departure from this, and numpy 'forgets' that masked elements are present.

```
def build_poly(x, degree):
    """polynomial basis functions for input data x, for j=0 up to j=degree."""
    D = len(x)
    polyome = np.ones((D, 1))
    for i in range(1, degree+1):
        polyome = np.ma.concatenate([polyome, np.ma.power(x,i)], axis=1)
    return polyome
```

Comment: Right, the key is to use the 'masked' aware version of `concatenate`.

Comment: Not to mention `ma.power`.

Comment: Though `masked_x**2` works just as well for me.  Via `__pow__` it delegates to `np.ma.power`.

Comment: okay, thanks !! Do you know another way to omit some specific elements of a 2d array when computing  ?

Comment: @hpaulj: Not something I knew. I was mainly concerned that someone referring to this question wouldn't miss that both places in the code needed attention.

Comment: @totyped; if you want to omit values, yet preserve array shapes (e.g. 2d here).then masked arrays are the best.  You can use a boolean mask to remove items from an array, but that flattens the result (you can't store 5 values in a (2,3) array).