# How can I compute things, but omit certain numpy elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of data, which I would like to standardize. However within the set, there are some numbers which I do not want to use (outliers).

Therefore, more generally, **is there a way to do array computations and omitting certain array elements in numpy** ?

Comment: Yes there is a way.  If you were to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would greatly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876004/numpy-masked-elements-in-computation uses `Masked_array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your numpy array is implemented, you may be able to use conditional operations like the following:

```
import numpy as np

# Instantiates a sample array.
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

# Sets the boundary conditions of the operation.
x_min = 2
x_max = 4

# Performs an operation on elements satisfying the boundary conditions.
x[(x_min <= x) & (x <= x_max)] += 10
```

In this case, before the conditional operation, `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. However, after the conditional operation, `x = [1, 12, 13, 14, 5]`. That is, it is only operating on those elements satisfying the boundary conditions.

You could also use the numpy [`where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function to accomplish the same thing:

```
x[np.where((x_min <= x) & (x <= x_max))] += 10
```

However, if you wanted to omit the undesired values from the array entirely, you can use any of the following:

1. `x = x[(x_min <= x) & (x <= x_max)]`
2. `x = x[np.where((x_min <= x) & (x <= x_max))]`
3. `x = np.delete(x, np.where(~(x_min <= x) | ~(x <= x_max)))`

For which after the assignment, `x = [2 3 4]`, those elements satisfying the boundary conditions.